# Do i need to install xcode to install homebrew to install RUBY to install COMPASS to use SUSY?

Tags: ruby, sass, frameworks, compass-sass, susy-compass

Why do I need to install so much just to use Susy or about any sass framework?

I got really interested in using sass and sass frameworks but I can't figure out a right way to start using it. I don't get why I need to have so much installed to use just one thing. Also, I have never installed something through some sort of terminal so this freaks my out immensely, why can't I just download a zip file.

If know a useful tutorial on where to start, that would also help.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compass is not required for Susy. In fact, Compass is no longer maintained, so I highly recommend against using it. Susy only requires Sass, but you can use any flavor of Sass - Libsass, Ruby Sass, Node Sass, Gulp Sass, etc. If it compiles Sass, it will work with Susy. There are instructions for various setups in the [Susy docs](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/install/).

Susy also doesn't require command-line knowledge itself, though Sass is often compiled that way. There are tools that provide GUI wrappers for Sass, if you aren't comfortable in the command line. I think CodeKit ships with Susy included.

Comment: Thanks, I am still not comfortable with command lines, but i used it anyway because it was the easiest way for installing both sass and susy. I'll look into different types of sass, i thought there was only one. I use a version of compass to make a directory. Should i stopp doing that soon if compass is no longer maintained?

Comment: Yes, I would advise dropping Compass. I assume that means you installed Susy as a ruby gem? I think it's simpler to use NPM for package management, because the files are stored locally, and you can reference them directly without help from Compass.

Answer (score 1):

Your Mac already comes with a version of Ruby (with Sierra even a recent enough version). Unless you are actively develping on different versions of Ruby, you don't need to install a custom Ruby (or even a ruby version manager).

You probably still need a compiler. Here, the xcode command line tools are sufficient. You can install them with `xcode-select --install`.

Generally, all these tools are comand-line oriented. It will help you tremendously if you try to get at least a high-level understanding of how the command line works and how you can use it with your tools. This will also help you when it comes to deploy your solution to a live-server, often running Linux with just the command line.